# New Instance of Outlook not being recognized in solution

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

I have code that is used to create a new appointment for Outlook in C#

Unfortunatly, when I set the new instance of Outlook

```
Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application(); // creates new outlook app
```

"outlookApp" is not being recognised in the next line, (error Error 24  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property '
)
    Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);

Entire code for reference.

```
Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application(); // creates new outlook app
Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppointment = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem); // creates a new appointment

oAppointment.Subject = "Holiday request for " + name ; // set the subject
oAppointment.Body = " "; // set the body / send details of contact form below
oAppointment.Location = "Nicks Desk!"; // set the location
oAppointment.Start = Convert.ToDateTime(notesDate); // Set the start date NEEDS TO BE THE DATE THAT THE USER ENTERS IN DATEFROM
oAppointment.End = Convert.ToDateTime(notesDate); // End date NEEDS TO BE THE DATE THAT THE USER ENTERS IN DATETO
oAppointment.ReminderSet = true; // Set the reminder
oAppointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 15; // reminder time
oAppointment.Importance = Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh; // appointment importance
oAppointment.BusyStatus = Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;

oAppointment.Save(); 
Outlook.MailItem mailItem = oAppointment.ForwardAsVcal(); 
//who is sending the email
mailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName = NameInput;
// email address to send to
mailItem.To = "mailto:me@decodedsolutions.co.uk">me@decodedsolutions.co.uk; 
// send 
mailItem.Send();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error 24 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property  

When regarding outlookApp

Answer (score 2):

As the error is trying to tell you, you cannot reference your instance (including other fields) in a field initializer, since they run before the constructor.

Move the initializer to a method.

Comment: what do you mean? I tried adding each section to different method but the rest of the program is then flagged.

Fixed it up and I am now getting ambiguity in mailItem.Send(); 

Warning 1 Ambiguity between method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.Send()' and non-method 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event.Send'. Using method group.

Comment: @Alex: you can't "do stuff" directly inside a class. A class can only contain definitions - fields, properties, methods, events and such. A class can't *directly* contain code that has to execute line-by-line, in order, "doing stuff" in a step-by-step way. Code like that - such as what you've posted - needs to go inside a method inside the class. If you're having trouble, I suggest you post all your code - everything within that one file - so that we can see exactly how it's currently organised and post an example of how you need to rearrange it.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in a comment, the error you're getting is:

> Error 24 A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property  outlookApp

It's not immediately clear from the code you've posted, but the fact that you're getting this error means that I suspect the entire code sample you've posted is directly contained within a class, and not within a method or constructor of that class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    // the code you posted is contained here
}
```

Of the code you posted, the first line is perfectly valid in this location. The second line, though, is illegal in this context, and so are many of the lines following it. When you're initializing the oAppointment field, you're doing so by using the outlookApp field - but field initializers aren't allowed to refer to other fields, since there's no guarantee of the order in which the fields will be initialized and so outlookApp may not even have a value.

The likelihood is that you need to move most or all of the code you posted into a constructor or method, where the lines you've written would be valid:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public void MyMethod()
    {
        // the code you posted should be contained here
    }
}
```

Exactly what MyClass and MyMethod look like, I don't have enough information to tell you.